# How to get the number of objects I received in JSON response?

Tags: apex, integration, json, apexrest

How can I count the number of objects I received in JSON response?
In the below response I got two objects (id:1234, id:2345) and I want a variable that shows the total number of objects received in response is 2.

1. I tried using **Object.keys(jsonBody).length** but this is not working
   in Salesforce.
2. I also tried
   **JSONParser = JSON.createdParser(jsonBody)** but this is not giving me the count of objects.

   ```
   [
   {
       "id" : 1234,
       "organization_id" : 9123,
       "location_id" : 123,
       "name" : "Organizatoin Name",
       "services" : [
           {
               "id" : 1234,
               "service_id" : 987

           },
           {
               "id" : 1234,
               "service_id" : 678
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       "id" : 2345,
       "organization_id" : 8123,
       "location_id" : 123,
       "name" : "Company Name",
       "services" : [
           {
               "id" : 2626,
               "service_id" : 987

           },
           {
               "id" : 2727,
               "service_id" : 678
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   ]

Note: Depending on the number of objects I receive in the response, I have to decide if had to make another callout for page=2

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can just discover the size by parsing:

```
List<Object> parsedData = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonBody);
System.debug(parsedData.size()); // Should output 2
```